# Problem of \qty with \bm

Tags: physics, bm

I used qty symbol and bm symbol but didn't work. Why does not work?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[ \bm{\qty(x)} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\boldsymbol{\qty{x}}`.

Comment: Why bold parentheses?

Comment: When I make a text bold, if there are parentheses in it, to make them bold too @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use packade `amsmath` and `\boldsymbol` instead `\bm`, and You will have

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \boldsymbol{\qty(x)} \]

\end{document}
```